# Power BI Parameters: Making a Parameter as Label:Value Type

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to pass a parameter to a stored procedure to retrieve a data from MSSQL source to a Power BI dataset, which is accepting specific values as an input.

Please refer the following table:

```
Label    |  Value
---------+-------
Male     |  M
Female   |  F
```

I want to show the value in the **Label** on the **report refresh prompt**, while passing the value on **Value** field to the Stored Proc.

The stored procedure does not accept the values in the **Label** field.

Anyone has a workaround for this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create a text parameter with list of values that are all possible label values (i.e. `Male` and `Female`):

[image]

Make a table that will contain the parameter value. Get data from `Blang query`:

[image]

and use expression like this:

```
= #table({"EmployeeGender"},{{#"EmployeeGender"}})
```

Then get the data from your database, but convert the parameter value (label value) to database value (actual value) using a `CASE` expression like this:

```
case {PARAMETER} when 'Male' then 'M' when 'Female' then 'F' end
```

Or in M:

```
= Sql.Database("SERVERNAME", "DATABASENAME", [Query="select * from dbo.SelectEmployees(case '" & EmployeeGender & "' when 'Male' then 'M' when 'Female' then 'F' end)"])
```

With `&` you can concatenate strings, `EmployeeGender` is the name of the parameter, which will be replaced with it's value (`Male` or `Female`) and then SQL Server will execute the `case` statement to decode the "label value" to "actual value" (i.e. `M` or `F`).

Then place the result returned from your query and the contents of your helper table in the report. When changing the parameter's value, you will see only those rows mathing current parameter value and will see the appropriate label:

[image]

Comment: I was hoping there is a easy way to do this directly via GUI (Like on SSRS). This worked like a charm.

Comment: If there is a scenario that we have to use more entries; 
e.g.: Passing **State Code** for **State Names**, while showing **State Codes** on the parameter prompt.

what would be the best approach?

Comment: But still using a stored procedure? This isn't a good fit for Power BI. Either change your SP to accept the values that is convenient for use in Power BI, or you have to do unnecessary twists to make it work (e.g. add a table with state code and name, use the parameter to filter the code and let the relation between state name and your report query to do the job).

Comment: I went with importing all the data from source and the state table separately (after modifying the SP), ending up filtering in the report itself using a slicer. The expected worse case scenario was exceeding the dataset limit of 1GB per "PBI Pro" license and this may wont be an issue with our unfiltered dataset size. 

And thanks very much for the support!

P.S: I tried that unnecessary twist too. Ended up getting **Formula.Firewall: Query references other queries or steps** error.